# Cite commands with same author Eg. Smith (1992 & 1993)

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing

I am asking almost the same question as [link for similar questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508006/how-to-put-a-both-year-together-in-referencing-eg-smith-1992-1993/508009#508009)

I want to have

```
Smith (1998 & 1999)
```

However, for this question, i added

```
style=authoryear-comp.
```

and

```
\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{\space\&\space}
```

to my MWE, is not working

It might be because of

```
citestyle=authoryear
```

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{journal1,
  title={title ABC},
  author={Smith, Bether},
  journal={Behavior Research Methods, Instruments, \& Computers},
  volume={24},
  number={2},
  pages={258--264},
  year={1992},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@article{journal2,
  title={title CBD},
  author={Smith, Bether},
  journal={Behavior Research Methods, Instruments, \& Computers},
  volume={25},
  number={2},
  pages={242--249},
  year={1993},
  publisher={Springer}
}


@article{journal2,
  title={journal123456},
  author={Abc, Def, GhI},
  journal={Journal of Neurology, Neurosurgery \& Psychiatry},
  volume={62},
  number={1},
  pages={22--26},
  year={1999},
}


\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear, 
  style=authoryear-comp, 
  backend=biber, 
  maxcitenames=2,
  giveninits,
 dashed=false,
  citestyle=authoryear,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % \jobname to use the bib file created with filecontents

\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given} %for second and third author name



% for references 's studies (year)
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyear{#1}}

% for combine both year for an author
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{\space\&\space}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printnames{labelname}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyear} % <======================================
    {}
    {(\bibhyperref{\printdate})}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}


\makeatletter
\let\abx@macro@textciteOrig\abx@macro@textcite
\renewbibmacro{textcite}{% <============================================
   \bibhyperref{%
   \let\bibhyperref\relax\relax%
   \abx@macro@textciteOrig%
   }%
}%
\makeatother
% for references 's studies (year)

\begin{document}



ABC studies is done by \textcite{journal1, journal2}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you have two `style` options and end with the `citestyle` option in your `biblatex` set up.

`style` sets both `citestyle` and `bibstyle`.

Remove them all and just leave `style=authoryear-comp`:

```
\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear-comp, 
  maxcitenames=2,
  giveninits,
  dashed=false,
]{biblatex}
```

Also, `backend=biber` is the default and not needed.

Using `authoryear-comp` also means you have to slightly change your redefinition of `\parencite`:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\parencite}[\mkbibparens]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

I also suspect your attempt to get the name to be a hyperlink with `\textcite` is going to cause you problems. Apart from the fact that the closing bracket isn't hyperlinked, which bibliography entry should the name point to? In this case it only makes sense to link the years. (Although, I guess it kind of works like you have it.)

Comment: Thanks. If I remove `citestyle=authoryear`, the `\parencite{}` is not working. It need `citestyle=authoryear`

Comment: @aan, that's because of other customisations you have made. I'll track down the problem.

Comment: @aan, you're missing `\usebibmacro{cite:init}` from your redefinition of `\parencite`. Look in `authoryear-comp.cbx` for the default definition.

Comment: thanks. it worked in my MWE. However, when I tried all the same setting in my real Overleaf thesis writing, it appears to be `Smith (1998), 1999)` which is wrong.

Comment: @aan, Either you have other customisations in your actual thesis that are breaking things. Or this is because the version of `biblatex` on overleaf is too old. I don't know which. You'll have to work backwards, cutting out customisations one by one until you know where the problem is.

Comment: thanks. I did try compare one by one, quite headache and maybe miss some line. Anyway, where to check my version of `biblatex` ?

Comment: Do you have an up to date local TeX install? What happens if you build your thesis on that? The latest version of `biblatex` is 3.13. You can add `\listfiles` at the top of any document and the log file will show you the version in use.

Comment: If your MWE (with my two changes) works on Overleaf, then the problem must be in other customisations in your thesis.

Comment: Thanks. I edited two changes `(redefination parencite, style)` I posted this question in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/508112/i-had-customisations-my-biblatex-result-is-smith-1992-1993-it-suppose-sm

Comment: One TeXnical (and not conceptual) problem of the `\parencite` definition that you rightly point out as problematic is discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/546403/35864. The `\printtext` in that position completely confuses the punctuation buffer.